N-Epsilon proof
I was working on the questions seen below. Namely question 7 and 8. I was able to figure them both out but noticed that in question 7 we do not include the absolute value sign after where it says "implies, $0 \lt $ ..." as per the definition.
Now I know that $\sqrt[n]{a} -1$ is always positive, but so too is $\sqrt[n]{n} -1.$ So why do we not omit the absolute value as well in question 8.
Additionally, how do I visualise and/or understand $ 0 \lt \sqrt[n]{a} - 1 \lt \epsilon$ since the neighbourhood is not the same distance from the limit on both sides.



$a^{1/n} -1$ is "always" (more precisely: if $a>1$) positive. "Why do we not omit the absolute value as well in question 8": you are right, we could. 2) $a^{1/n}\in(1,1+\epsilon)\subset(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$.


@AnneBauval thank you. Why are we allowed to take (1, 1 + ε) if it’s not the entire range we are after? Doesn’t that go against the definition?

The definition wanted $a^{1/n}\in(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$. We obtained $a^{1/n}\in(1,1+\epsilon)$, which is stronger, so we won.

That makes sense now. Thank you. I didn’t realise you replied.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

The first one seems where we invert $n(\sqrt[n]a -1) <a$ so $\sqrt[n]a-1 <\frac an$ gave use a positive upper bound but "left us hanging" on the lower bound.  But that's okay we had an immediate hack.  We know $\sqrt[n]a - 1>0$ so that gives us $0$ as a lower bound.  Now if we needed to be strictly formal we could have gone $-\epsilon < 0 < \sqrt[n]a - 1 < \frac an = \epsilon$ but there's no need to make trouble. The second one with an even power yields "naturally" to absolute values. So we weren't left hanging and we don't need to do the extra work of noting $\sqrt[n]n -1$ is always pos.

"Why are we allowed to take (1, 1 + ε) if it’s not the entire range we are after? Doesn’t that go against the definition?" We arent after the entire range.  To get the exact range and nothing but the range would be difficult and maybe impossible and absolutely not nesc.  But if we can get something that covers everything we need and then some and be a bit more than we need it is fine and great.
